# Why am I receiving a Webhook Message Delivery error on this POST request?

Tags: json, post, microsoft-teams

I tested the following JSON body on:

adaptivecards.io/designer

and I didn't face any issues with displaying the desired card. However, sending a POST request to my Teams Channel using an Incoming Webhook connector with this JSON body does not work.

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": 
    [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": 
            {
                "$schema": "https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.0",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "This card's action will show another card"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                        "title": "Action.ShowCard",
                        "card": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                            "version": "1.5",
                            "body": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Table",
                                    "gridStyle": "accent",
                                    "columns": [
                                        {
                                            "width": 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "width": 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "width": 3
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "rows": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TableRow",
                                            "cells": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Name",
                                                            "wrap": true,
                                                            "weight": "Bolder"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Type",
                                                            "wrap": true,
                                                            "weight": "Bolder"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Description",
                                                            "wrap": true,
                                                            "weight": "Bolder"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "style": "accent"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "TableRow",
                                            "cells": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "good",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "columns",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "warning",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "ColumnDefinition[]",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "accent",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Defines the table's columns (number of columns, and column sizes).",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "TableRow",
                                            "cells": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "good",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "rows",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "accent",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "TableRow[]",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "attention",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Defines the rows of the Table, each being a collection of cells. Rows are not required, which allows empty Tables to be generated via templating without breaking the rendering of the whole card.",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Table",
                                    "gridStyle": "accent",
                                    "showGridLines": false,
                                    "columns": [
                                        {
                                            "width": 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "width": 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "width": 3
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "rows": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TableRow",
                                            "cells": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Name",
                                                            "wrap": true,
                                                            "weight": "Bolder"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Type",
                                                            "wrap": true,
                                                            "weight": "Bolder"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Description",
                                                            "wrap": true,
                                                            "weight": "Bolder"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "style": "accent"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "TableRow",
                                            "cells": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "good",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "columns",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "warning",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "ColumnDefinition[]",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "accent",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Defines the table's columns (number of columns, and column sizes).",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "TableRow",
                                            "cells": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "good",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "rows",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "accent",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "TableRow[]",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "TableCell",
                                                    "style": "attention",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                                            "text": "Defines the rows of the Table, each being a collection of cells. Rows are not required, which allows empty Tables to be generated via templating without breaking the rendering of the whole card.",
                                                            "wrap": true
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            } 
        }
    ]
}
```

I should expect a card like this being sent to my MS Teams channel, however it results in the following error:

`Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400`

This is what I expect the Teams message to look like:

[image]

Any ideas for why this is happening?

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue, checking this with the internal team.

Comment: We have raised a bug for this issue. We will keep you posted on the updates.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is Adaptive Card v1.5 is not supported so Table element can't be parsed properly and Teams returns 400 error code.

We are actively working on the fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey Leon, do we have an update on this issue?

Comment: @AngoMango - We tested the above shared JSON and it is successfully sent via incoming webhook. Clicking on showcard button is displaying the table properly. Can you please check and confirm if it is working for you? Attaching screenshots for your reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFPVC.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myq7F.png. Thanks.